# What Methods are out there for Dynamic Location Referencing?

Tags: dynamic

I'm looking for (industry) standards and implementations to solve the problem of dynamic location referencing (communication of location between systems which have dissimilar maps).

I would like to communicate information from one system using a map from vendor A to another system using a map from vendor B. It's not possible to exchange the maps.

The only thing I've been able to find were:

- [OpenLR™](http://www.tomtom.com/page/openLR) by TomTom which is open source (but doesn't seem to have an active [community](http://www.openlr.org/forum/)), and
- AGORA-C a non-free [ISO standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=45962)

Do you know any other standards/methods to approach this problem? What's your experience with them?

Answer (score 2):

You might try: [Dynamic location: an iconic model to synchronize temporal and spatial transportation data](http://www.mendeley.com/research/dynamic-location-an-iconic-model-to-synchronize-temporal-and-spatial-transportation-data/). I heard [TxDOT](http://www.txdot.gov/) tried to implement this with limited success.